# Android - ImageView has somewhat like a padding

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have i weird problem. Or maybe i got it wrong. But my `ImageView` has somewhat like a padding. It looks like this:

[image]

So the "MyImage"  is supposed to align to the topmost. But instead when I check the Graphical Layout the image is adjusted lower. So it's like my whole image is the green broken line.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/master_background">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/topPage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my code. I tried to change `src` to `background` but my image was adjusted.
How can i adjust the image.  This application doesn't have window title.

Comment: Tried with different scaleTypes?

Comment: Are you definitely sure the padding isn't in your actual bitmap? Whitespace/transparent space at the top?

Comment: i dont see any padding, set ImageView's background for testing purposes to, say, "#f00" and see the difference

Comment: yes. i did not get what i wanted. although it aligns to the top but the image is rescaled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your image view.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/topPage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Comment: right, i totally forgot  `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`. Thank you